# How to implement asyncTask as Coroutines

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have an adapter class where I used the db.

```
class RestaurantRecycleAdapter(val context: Context, private var itemList: ArrayList<Restaurant>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RestaurantRecycleAdapter.RestaurantViewHolder>() {
    class RestaurantViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        val txtFav: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.favTextView)
        val txtRestaurantName: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtFoodName)
        val txtRestaurantRating: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtFoodRating)
        val txtRestaurantPrice: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtFoodPrice)
        val restaurantImage: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.foodImageView)
        val rlContent: RelativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.rlContent)

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RestaurantViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_dashboard, parent, false)

        return RestaurantViewHolder(view)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RestaurantViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val restaurant = itemList[position]
        val restaurantEntity = RestaurantEntity(restaurant.restaurantId, restaurant.restaurantName)

        holder.txtRestaurantName.text = restaurant.restaurantName
        holder.txtRestaurantRating.text = restaurant.restaurantRating
        holder.txtRestaurantPrice.text = "${restaurant.restaurantPrice}/Person"

        Picasso.get().load(restaurant.restaurantImage).error(R.drawable.restaurant_image)
            .into(holder.restaurantImage)

        holder.rlContent.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(context, RestaurantMenuActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("restaurantId", restaurant.restaurantId)
            intent.putExtra("restaurantName", restaurant.restaurantName)
            intent.putExtra("restaurantImage",restaurant.restaurantImage.toString())
            intent.putExtra("restaurantPrice", restaurant.restaurantPrice.toString())
            intent.putExtra("restaurantRating", restaurant.restaurantRating.toString())
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }

        **val checkFav = DBAsyncTask(context, restaurantEntity, 1).execute()
        val isFav = checkFav.get()**

        if (isFav) {
            holder.txtFav.tag = "liked"
            holder.txtFav.background = context.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_fav_fill)
        } else {
            holder.txtFav.tag = "unliked"
            holder.txtFav.background = context.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_fav_outline)
        }

        holder.txtFav.setOnClickListener {
            **if (!DBAsyncTask(context, restaurantEntity, 1).execute().get()) {
                val result = DBAsyncTask(context, restaurantEntity, 2).execute().get()**
                if (result) {
                    StyleableToast.Builder(context).text("${restaurant.restaurantName} Added To Fav")
                        .textColor(Color.WHITE)
                        .iconStart(R.drawable.ic_favorite)
                        .length(100)
                        .backgroundColor(Color.RED)
                        .show()
                    holder.txtFav.tag = "liked"
                    holder.txtFav.background = context.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_fav_fill)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "Database error. Please Try Again",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            } else {
                **val result = DBAsyncTask(context, restaurantEntity, 3).execute().get()**
                if (result) {
                    StyleableToast.Builder(context).text("${restaurant.restaurantName} Removed From Fav")
                        .textColor(Color.WHITE)
                        .iconStart(R.drawable.ic_favorite)
                        .length(100)
                        .backgroundColor(Color.RED)
                        .show()
                    holder.txtFav.tag = "unliked"
                    holder.txtFav.background =
                        context.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_fav_outline)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "Database error. Please Try Again",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemList.size
    }


}
```

I have highlighted the place where I have used the db.

This is the db class

```
 class DBQueries(val context: Context, val restaurantEntity: RestaurantEntity, val mode: Int, application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val db:RestaurantDatabase = RestaurantDatabase.getInstance(application)
    var flag: Boolean = true
    fun insert(): Boolean {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            when(mode) {
                1 -> {
                    val restaurant: RestaurantEntity =
                        db.restaurantDao().getAllRestaurant(restaurantEntity.restaurant_Id)
                    db.close()
                    return@launch

                }

                2 -> {
                    db.restaurantDao().insertRestaurant(restaurantEntity)
                    db.close()
                    return@launch

                }

                3 -> {
                    db.restaurantDao().deleteRestaurant(restaurantEntity)
                    db.close()
                    return@launch

                }

            }

        }
        return false
    }
}
```

This is the RestaurantDatabase class:

```
@Database(entities = [RestaurantEntity::class], version = 1)
abstract class RestaurantDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun restaurantDao(): RestaurantDao

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: RestaurantDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): RestaurantDatabase {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    RestaurantDatabase::class.java,
                    "restaurant-db")
                    .build()
            }
            return INSTANCE as RestaurantDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't actually working properly. The list is not the proper one.
Also I want to change the AsyncTask to Coroutines. I tried implementing coroutines by extending CoroutinesScope and calling GlobalScope inside the class. But It isn't working at all.

Please help me

Comment: In my suggestion, adapter's job is just to display or give information if the user has interacted with the view displayed using the adapter. The adapter should give callback to the calling fragment. The fragment can decide the operation needed to be done on the interaction. In your case, you will call the API using coroutine. DB operations are also not advisable to be done in the adapter. You are passing context to the adapter. This can introduce leaks.

Comment: Then should I create a seperate class for it ??

Comment: Your question is too broad I think. Try to implement it and then come back with more specific questions about any problem you encounter. I suggest you start by doing some simple examples of coroutines until you get the hang of it, then try to replace the async task with coroutines.

Comment: The Adapter shouldn't even be aware that a database exists. It's only job should be to connect a List of something to views and fire callbacks when there's user input on those views. The host Activity or Fragment can implement the callbacks that react to button presses, for example.

Comment: But if you were going to use coroutines in your Adapter, you should have a CoroutineScope property that can be set in the constructor. Whichever Activity or Fragment hosts the Adapter can pass it its own `lifecycleScope`. The Adapter can launch coroutines from that scope. Then they will automatically be cancelled if the Activity/Fragment life ends.

Comment: Since I'using the db class in adapter " val checkFav = DBAsyncTask(context, restaurantEntity, 1).execute()
        val isFav = checkFav.get()"

Comment: @yazhini please check this article. It explains how you can have a clickListener and use it for callbacks to the fragment. You can pass the instance in adapter constructor. Then the fragment which is implementing this listener will get the callback. Your callback function can pass the object that you want to use for making the API call. https://aayushpuranik.medium.com/recycler-view-using-kotlin-with-click-listener-46e7884eaf59

Answer (score 1):

Room supports coroutines so I guess you must declare suspended functions your DAO methods and instead of using your async task you can move those methods to the IO and make the main-thread safe you can find more info [here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines#use-coroutines-for-main-safety)

```
class DBQueries() {
  val db = Room.databaseBuilder(context, RestaurantDatabase::class.java, "restaurant-db").build()
  suspend fun insertRestaurant(restaurantEntity: RestaurantEntity): Boolean  { 
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
      val restaurant: Int =
                db.restaurantDao().insertRestaurant(restaurantEntity)
            db.close()
     restaurant > -1
  }
}
```

And in order to connect this with the lifecycle you should move the click event to the main view(fragment or activity) you can use an interface for it or livedata.

Comment: I have edited it, can u look into that ??

Comment: you must refactor your code in order to access a lifecycle scope easily, you can make use a [liveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) to return events values to the main screen and make use of the lifecycle of that view.